# Indexes lost after restart elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

After restarting ES,Indexes are there in the destined folder but aren't visible on

`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'`

Indexes are of large size (> 100GB)

Comment: When this happens, check your `_cluster/health`, maybe you have shards that are still initializing?

Comment: All of the shards have started.